# In python interpreters, why are results different between using an explicit "print" and not using it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing, python-idle, read-eval-print-loop

```
>>> 'sp\xc4m'
'sp\xc4m'
>>> print('sp\xc4m')
spÄm
```

([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSMCo.png))

In IDLE,I think that using the function "print" and not using it should be the same. And the book "Learning Python(5th)" supports my opinion.

```
>>> lumberjack = 'okay'
>>> lumberjack
'okay'
```

[example from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFVJK.png)

I am a freshman in python, and my mother language isn't English, so maybe my question and expression are funny, but I keep learning. Thank you for your help.

Comment: only a little funny ;-) Maybe You could give a very short example of why You think the behaviour is different?
-
I believe I can assure You that the problem is not in the print statement.

Comment: IDLE's shell is a GUI version of Python's interactive interpreter console text shell.  It is intended that it give the same result for the same input, and it does so here.  So this question is really about 'In Python'.  If the book had continued with `>>> print(lumberjack)`, it would have shown `okay`, without quotes, as copied from the interactive interpreter.

Comment: The example shows two differences.  The first, the absence or presence of quotes, is explained in the answers about `str` versus `repr`, which remain the same in 3.x.  The second, the escaping of the non-ascii char, is specific to 2.x.  In 3.x, `'sp\xc4m'` is echoed as `'spÄm'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interactive interpreter in IDLE is helpful for debugging.  If I wrote:

```
>>> print s
a       b
```

What is actually contained in the variable `s`?  You can check:

```
>>> s
'a\tb'
```

Now you can see that it is three characters, `a`, a tab displayed as the escape sequence `\t`, and `b`.  It could have been `'a       b'` (nine characters with spaces) or `'a       b   ' (twelve characters with trailing spaces).  Both print the same way, but the debugging representation helps determine the exact content via escape codes and quoting the string to visualize the start and end points.

This is called the "representation" of the variable, and is a debug value that can be accessed by the function `repr()`.  IDLE uses it to display variables that weren't explicitly printed.

At the interactive prompt, displaying a variable without `print` is for debugging.  Not using `print` in a script would display nothing.  To force display of the debugging value in a script, use `print repr(s)`.

Comment: Thank you very much.Now I can explain the results in python 2.7.But in python 3.5,the result of repr() is different,could you explain it?What's more,are you programming in the python 2.7?Why does it go wrong when I write like you.

Comment: @Vansiee, in Python 3 *printable* non-ASCII characters output directly without escape codes if the terminal encoding supports them.  If you want to see all non-ASCII characters as escape codes, use `ascii()` instead of `repr()` on Python 3.  `repr()` still a debugging value and will quote the string and show unprintable characters as escape codes, but it is more international friendly.

Answer (score 3):

IDLE prints the `repr` of a string (or anything else).

```
>>> print 'sp\xc4m'
sp?m
>>> 'sp\xc4m'
'sp\xc4m'
>>> print repr('sp\xc4m')
'sp\xc4m'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you,and it works in Version 2.7(maybe 2.X).In Version 3.5(maybe 3.X),when write 'sp\xc4m' only,the result is the 'spÄm'.

Answer (score 1):

The interactive interpreter's auto-print behavior is equivalent to

```
_ = the_expression_you_typed
if _ is not None:
    print repr(_)
```

Besides the `None` thing, this differs from `print _` in that `print _` would call `str` instead of `repr`. Ostensibly, the difference between `str` and `repr` is that `str` is supposed to produce more human-readable output, while `repr` is supposed to produce something unambiguous, ideally a piece of source code that would produce the object.

[Really, though, the main reason the two functions exist is so `print "asdf"` prints `asdf` and just typing `"asdf"` prints `"asdf"`.](http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.ppt)

Comment: Oh,I see.Thank you very much.In python 2.7,using 'print' means the function 'str',which is more understandable.And not using 'print' means the function 'repr',in which people can read the profound meanings of the code.But it works in python 2.7,but in python 3.5,the results of using 'print' and not using 'print' are same.In python 3.5,when write str('sp\xc4m'),the result is 'spÄm',but when write repr('sp\xc4m'),the result is "'spÄm'".Is the function of 'repr' changed?

Comment: @Vansiee: They're not the same, but `repr` has become more willing to use non-ASCII characters in its output in Python 3.